# SPIDRV API port pin definition

Tags: embedded, spi

I Need to communicate my EFM32LG with a dac80004 USING SPI.
When i define USART in SPI mode i need to define the pins and ports as follwoing:
Port A pin 2: chip select sync_not (active low)
Port E pin 10: MOSI (SDIN)
Port E pin 11: MISO (serial interface digital out)
Port E pin 12: SCLK
Port A pin 1: clear DAC pin

From the API shown in the link bellow,I have only _USART_ROUTE_LOCATION_LOC0 .
How do i Put set my actual locations Using the API of SPIDRV?
Thanks.\

https://docs.silabs.com/mcu/latest/efm32lg/group-SPIDRV#gaec2cac185e42ded3da0d3e2d5cd56226
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The values listed there are the *defaults*, they're not the only option.

If you look at the [EFM32LG datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efm32lg-datasheet.pdf), page 352 there are other locations where you can set up the `USART0` SPI pins.

Location 0 is fine for MOSI, MISO and CLK, but the CS would need to be PE13 if you want it driver controlled.

Alternatively, you could alter `spidrvCsControlAuto` to `spidrvCsControlApplication` and control the CS manually as a GPIO.

Comment: Hello DaV,When i choose to go with the alternative way ,what about the CSPEN bit field in USARTn_ROUTE register.
should i disable it?
Thnaks.

Comment: Yes. However if you change `spiDrvCsControlAuto` to `spidrvCsControlApplication`, the driver will do this for you. Check out `SPIDRV_Init()` in `platform/emdrv/spidrv/src/spidrv.c`.

Comment: Hello, I cant deside what command to choose for data tranfer to the slave

SPIDRV_MTransmitB(handle, B31_B24, 8);
or

SPIDRV_MTransmit?
Thanks.

Comment: @rocko445, I think you'll find the blocking version of the function `SPIDRV_MTransmitB()` easier to use.

Comment: Hello Dav, I Have defined  
uint8_t B31_B24=0b00000011;  as the command i want to send to myDAC
But when i do  SPIDRV_MTransmitB(handle, B31_B24, 8); it gives me an error of
SPIDRV_MTransmitB' makes pointer from integer without a cast.
Where did i go wrong?
Thanks

Comment: For the second parameter? You probably need `SPIDRV_MTransmitB(handle, &B31_B24, 1);` The second parameter needs to be a pointer, not an integer. Note that the third parameter is number of _bytes_, not bits.

Comment: Hello DaV, regarding the manual CS command sending.
Recieve: 32bit data recieved at once
 GPIO_PinOutClear(LED_PORT_A,2);

 SPIDRV_MReceiveB(handle,&Recieved_D,4);

GPIO_PinOutSet(LED_PORT_A,2);

GPIO_PinOutClear(LED_PORT_A,2); //chip select low starts transmition
SPIDRV_MTransmitB(handle, &F31_F24, 1);
 SPIDRV_MTransmitB(handle, &F23_F16, 1);

SPIDRV_MTransmitB(handle, &F15_F8, 1);\\
SPIDRV_MTransmitB(handle, &F7_F0, 1); \\
GPIO_PinOutSet(LED_PORT_A,2); // chip select high,end transmition
is it the way we send commands with manual CS?

Comment: @rocko445. Check the datasheet for the DAC you're trying to talk to as it most likely gives examples. In general yes, you put the CS (chip select) low to ready the chip for the command you're about to transmit, perform the SPI transmit & receive, and then set CS high to complete the transaction.

Comment: Hello, i am confused regarding the pointer issues in the commands bellow.

Did i define the uint data correctly for SPIDRV_MTransmitB and  SPIDRV_MReceiveB?

so  my recieved data will be stored as uint in Recieved_D ,and the data in B&_B0 will be transferred.
For SENDING:
given uint8_t B7_B0=0b11110000; i want to send it threw my SPIDRV.
SPIDRV_MTransmitB(handle, &B7_B0, 1);

For recieving:

     GPIO_PinOutClear(LED_PORT_A,2);
       SPIDRV_MReceiveB(handle,&Recieved_D,4);
      GPIO_PinOutSet(LED_PORT_A,2);

Thanks.

Comment: Received_D should probably be `uint8_t Recieved_D[4]` or larger. `SPIDRV_MReceiveB()` expects a buffer to store the received data. The third parameter is the number of bytes to receive. If you have additional quedtions, make a new question. That way others can benefit from the responses.

Comment: Hello Dav, regarding the recieve command i should uint8 array and 4 bytes or one uint32?  
Thanks.(yes i will post next new thread) 
uint8_t Recieved_D[4];  
 SPIDRV_MReceiveB(handle,&Recieved_D,4);  

OR
uint32_t Recieved_D;  
 SPIDRV_MReceiveB(handle,&Recieved_D,4);